# Materialize chip autocomplete dropdown width

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, materialize

i am getting crazy in trying with this task:
i have a modal width 75% which has an input

```
        <div id="pippo" class="chips chips-autocomplete"></div>
        <label for="pippo">Scope</label>
```

where basically i want to have the user to get indications of the chips to use according to the autocomplete.

```
$('.chips-autocomplete').chips({
autocompleteOptions: {
  data: tags,
  limit: Infinity,
  minLength: 1}
});
```

nevertheless my dropdown content comes with width 120px, which is too narrow and i cannot find how to enlarge or unconstrain.

yes, i also tried `$('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({constrainWidth:false})` without luck (i guess it works on normal dropdowns but not the autocomplete ones?)
does anyone knows the solution?
please see here an image of the issue:

[image: dropdown in the chips autocomplete]

here you see a fiddle of the problem: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3agb09L/1/)
thank you so much

lorenzo

Comment: can you show an image of what you mean

Comment: just increase the width of `.dropdown-content`

Comment: @לבנימלכה i added the image.

Comment: @SeanDoherty i tried in all ways i knew and that has no impact. can you please give some suggestions?

Comment: Build a codepen - reduced example of your problem.

Comment: @SeanDoherty good idea, i added a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `!important` flag to override, as the css gets applied inline via Javascript:

```
.dropdown-content {
  width:200px !important;
}
```